# Стиль span прерывается тегом br! Почему?

Tags: css

Доброго кодинга всем.
Вопрос такой - 
Почему стиль span прерывается тегом br! И главное не весь, а только margin?
Ни цвет, ни шрифт, а только отступ?
Пример:

```
<span style="font: normal 12px 'trebuchet MS'; padding-bottom:5px; margin-left:25px; color:#FF0000;">
Для определение оператора <br />введите номер телефона:
</span>
```

*(Браузер FF)*

Comment: Потому что span это строчный элемент, для таких целей лучше использовать блочные элементы div. А в данном случае добавьте display: block;, чтобы элемент стал блочным.

Comment: [Не вижу][1], чтоб что-то там "перекрывалось". Возможно, что какие-то еще стили влияют.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/H2V98/

Comment: @Deonis не перекрывается, а прерывается. У него у второй строчки отступ не делается.

Comment: Все вопросы по CSS на данном ресурсе какие-то непонятные. В стиле: "У меня есть вот что. Почему неправильно отображается?". А что собственно получить надо-то? Прикладывайте картинку, что надо и что есть.

По теме: [оно?][1]


  [1]: http://jsbin.com/OHegUqo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @andrew68 то же самое написал. В данном случае разницы нет между `display: inline-block;` и `display: block;`

Comment: Разница в данном случае, да и вообще есть. При display:block элемент будет занимать всю доступную ширину (если дополнительно ничего не делать), при display:inline-block ширина элемента будет равна ширине контента. То есть, если рядом будут две такие кнопки, то в первом случае они будут располагаться друг под другом, а во втором - рядом в одной строке. По делу: решение не устраивает?

Comment: @Отоно Как, Ведь @andrew68 предложил решение. Вы лишь повторили, при том, что я не говорил про ДВА таких элемента.  
И если ученик пишет 2+2=3, а ведь нужно, что бы было 2+2=4, то **Хороший** учитель, вряд ли для себя заставит рисовать ученика картинки, дабы понять, что хочет от него ученик.
А @andrew68 из-за своей скромности, даже не пытается свой комментарий сделать ответом.
А Вы чуть ли не требуете.